# Trouble with Tab Order using Frames

Tags: excel, vba

I have a form with MultiPage. On Page 3, I have three frames with comboboxes a next button and a back button. This is the tab order I have.

```
Frame1 with Tab order 0
     TextBox1 Tab Order 0
     TextBox2 Tab Order 1
     TextBox3 Tab Order 2
     TextBox4 Tab Order 3
Frame2 with Tab order 1
     TextBox5 Tab Order 0
     TextBox6 Tab Order 1
Frame3 with Tab order 2
     TextBox7 Tab Order 0
     TextBox8 Tab Order 1
Next Button with Tab Order 3
Back Button with Tab Order 4
```

I can tab through the textboxes inside "Frame with Tab order 0". THEN, I have to hit tab 3 times before the cursor arrives at "Frame with Tab order 1, TextBox with Tab order 0". After that it works fine. I'm not sure where the focus is even going during those 3 tabs. Please help. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just see textbox, shouldn't it be textbox1,textbox2

I like to just set the textboxes manually, go to view and select tab order

[image: tab1]

Then set the tab order there.

[image: tab2]

Comment: Thank you @Davesexcel  !! I wasn't aware of the TAB ORDER view, and this helped me to see where the focus was going during those three extra TABS. I was able to place the order exactly as I wanted. It seems it can get tricky when frames are involved. Greatly appreciated. . :)